# How to know in which direction my gps is going?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working with google maps api and at some point, I need to show in which direction I am currently going. For example, I am going from A station to D station. In the middle, there are B and then C stations. Suppose my position in the middle of B and C. How can I show/know I am currently moving to C Station or B station.

I am showing the position with a marker. But also I want to show that the next station is approx 5 or any KM. How can I get this type of distance?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can use the geometry library.

The Spherical namespace has 2 methods that you can use:

- [`computeDistanceBetween()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/geometry#spherical.computeDistanceBetween)
- [`computeHeading()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/geometry#spherical.computeHeading).

So you can easily pass your current user location and the next station to get the distance. To get the heading, you could keep your user's last position and compare it with the current one to get the heading.

You need to load the Geometry library when loading the api:

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=your_api_key">`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. After using computeHeading() I got a point for Position A to B is 138.96925791629974. and from position B to A is -40.472947224734355. How to use this point and know which direction it is going. from A to B or B to A?

Comment: I don't understand your question. 0 (or 360) is north and 180 is south. That said it doesn't make sense that you get a negative number in return. Update your question with the code you have so far.